# How to assign something to global variable from within FOR loop in batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, global-variables

I have some code, which is get some string from file and assign it to some variable. The variable will be used for different purpose in file:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`file.txt`) DO SET var1=%%F
endlocal
echo %var1%
```

I get empty `var1`. How can I extract string and use it for my purposes in different places?

Comment: Why are you closing the environment with the end local?

Comment: `endlocal & set "var1=%var1%"`. `%var1%` is expanded within the "local", but the `set` is executed outside the "local".

Comment: If you really need to close the environment you can just use this: endlocal & set var1=%var1%

Comment: Unfortunanly, I have no success yet

Comment: You need to put double quotes around the file name when using the USEBACKQ option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one.

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN ("file.txt") DO Set "var1=!var1!%%F"
Echo !var1!
```

Simply do not do `endlocal` as per above as it will endlocal as soon as the script exists. If however you want to do it for each line in a string outside the loop, it is best to call a sub routine instead.

Comment: I need to use `var1` outside the FOR loop, but `var1` is nothing outside

Comment: @Sergio but using `var1` outside the for loop will only print the last var set, is that what you want?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard global aim is to extract some string from file and use it as argument for another command in different place in script. First time `var1` is empty

Comment: @Sergio Keep in mind, the setlocal and endlocal does not form part of the loop, just so you know. it simply sets when expansion and other functions are used and ended.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Thank you